# How to make only one of the variables have the value of 0?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to make it so that of the 4 variables, (squareType1, squareType2, squareType3, and squareType4) only one of them has a value of 0 but which variable it is should be random. The coding is off I know that but I just don't know how to fix it.

```
    squareType1 = arc4random() %2;
    squareType2 = arc4random() %2;
    squareType3 = arc4random() %2;
    squareType4 = arc4random() %2;

    if (squareType2 == 0 || squareType3 == 0 || squareType4 == 0) {
        squareType1 = 1;
    }
    if (squareType1 == 0 || squareType3 == 0 || squareType4 == 0) {
        squareType2 = 1;
    }
    if (squareType2 == 0 || squareType1 == 0 || squareType4 == 0) {
        squareType3 = 1;
    }
    if (squareType2 == 0 || squareType3 == 0 || squareType1 == 0) {
        squareType4 = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler way to do this would be to set all 4 values to 1 initially and then randomly reset one of the variables to 0, e.g.

```
squareType1 = squareType2 = squareType3 = squareType4 = 1;
switch (arc4random() % 4)
{
    case 0: squareType1 = 0; break;
    case 1: squareType2 = 0; break;
    case 2: squareType3 = 0; break;
    case 3: squareType4 = 0; break;
}
```

Note that you will probably find life easier, in this instance and in general, if you refactor the four separate variables into a single array, e.g. `int squareType[4];`.